# Solve two variable recursive equation in Mathematica, is that possible?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I tried to use `RSolve` to solve a two variable recursive equation in *Mathematica*, but it simply repeats what I type.

Is it possible to solve two variable recursive equations in *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should include the equation in your question, as it is possible you are simply using `RSolve` incorrectly.

*Mathematica* can solve some two-variable recurrence equations, but not all.

Sometimes [the free package `Guess.m`](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/Guess/) can solve what `RSolve` cannot.  (You must request access to the file; contact information is on that page.)

Answer (score 2):

I discovered `RecurrenceTable[]` today while trying to plot the Logistic map. It gives a table of values, symbolic if you like, given a set of recurrence relations and initial conditions. Oh, and it's really fast.

For example,

`logisticMap[r_,x0_,maxn_]:=RecurrenceTable[{x[n+1]==r x[n](1-x[n]),x[0]==x0},x,{n,0,nmax}];`
`Manipulate[ListPlot[Transpose[{Range[0,maxn],logisticMap[r,x0,maxn]}],PlotRange->{0,1}],{{r,3.485},0,4},{{x0,0.432},0,1},{{maxn,500},10,1000,1}]`

[image: Logistic Map Example]

The documentation for `RecurrenceTable` gives examples for two-variable relations.